# Having trouble with symmetry (equivalence relation)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Define a relation of $x,y \in R$ when $x = |y|$.

I know this is reflexive as $x = |x|$ holds true because the relation has to have x as positive since $x = |y|$ which makes $x$ have to be positive or $0$ to be in the defined relation.

Transitivity also follows...

But for symmetery I have a question:

Would it be $|y| = x$ or rather would it be:  $y = |x|$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't yet told on what set is the relation defined...

Comment: @DonAntonio pretty sure he did? x,y∈R

Comment: @bob how do you know transitivity follows?

Comment: If your relation is $\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:x=|y|\}$, then it’s not reflexive: $\langle -1,-1\rangle$ is not in the relation.

Comment: Using R both for "reals" and "relation" sure will lead to confusions, uh @Mac ?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott but wouldnt it not be in the relation in the first place if x < 0 since if it is then y will never be equal ?

Comment: @bobdole21: If the relation is on $\Bbb R$, then in order for it to be reflexive, it must contain $\langle x,x\rangle$ for **every** real number.

Comment: @StefanSmith Thanks for clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 1):

If the relation is defined on the real numbers then it isn't reflexive since for example $\;-1\rlap{\,/}R\, -1\;$, because $\;-1\neq|-1|=1\;$

It isn't symmetric since $\;1R-1\;$ but $\;-1\rlap{\,/}R\;1\;$

I'll leave transitivity for you, which shall be easier now after the above.

Answer (score 1):

For symmetry, you need $xRy \implies yRx$  Using the definition of $R$ that would mean that $x=|y| \implies y=|x|$.  Is that true?